# TSQL How to get the 2nd number from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have the below in row in MS SQL:

`Got event with: 123.123.123.123, event 34, brown fox`

How can we extract the 2nd number ie the 34 reliable in one line of SQL?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question.  Is the above data a single string and you want to extract the 34?  Will it always be the first number after the first comma?

Comment: is that number always after the string `'event'`?

Comment: Hi, yes 1 string ie the above and yes the 34 number will always be after the first comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've thought of another way that's not been mentioned yet. Presuming the following are true:

- Always one comma before the second "part"
- It's always the word "event" with the number in the second part
- You are using SQL Server 2005+

Then you could use the built in [`ParseName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) function meant for parsing the SysName datatype.

```
--Variable to hold your example
DECLARE @test NVARCHAR(50)
SET @test = 'Got event with: 123.123.123.123, event 34, brown fox'

SELECT Ltrim(Rtrim(Replace(Parsename(Replace(Replace(@test, '.', ''), ',', '.'), 2), 'event', '')))
```

Results:

> 34

`ParseName` parses around dots, but we want it to parse around commas. Here's the logic of what I've done:

1. Remove all existing dots in the string, in this case swap them with empty string.
2. Swap all commas for dots for `ParseName` to use
3. Use `ParseName` and ask for the second "piece". In your example this gives us the value
   " event 34".
4. Remove the word "event" from the string.
5. Trim both ends and return the value.

I've no comments on performance vs. the other solutions, and it looks just as messy. Thought I'd throw the idea out there anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it using `SUBSTRING` and `PATINDEX` -- I used a CTE just so it wouldn't look so awful :)

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT
     SUBSTRING(Data,CHARINDEX(',',Data)+1,LEN(Data)) data
  FROM Test
  )
SELECT LEFT(SUBSTRING(Data, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Data), 8000), 
         PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', 
         SUBSTRING(Data, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Data), 8000) + 'X')-1)
FROM CTE
```

And here is some sample [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e8a52/2).

As commented, CTEs will only work with 2005 and higher.  If by chance you're using 2000, then this will work without the CTE:

```
SELECT LEFT(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(Data,CHARINDEX(',',Data)+1,LEN(Data)), 
         PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', SUBSTRING(Data,CHARINDEX(',',Data)+1,LEN(Data))), 8000), 
         PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', 
         SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(Data,CHARINDEX(',',Data)+1,LEN(Data)), 
         PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', SUBSTRING(Data,CHARINDEX(',',Data)+1,LEN(Data))), 8000) + 'X')-1)
FROM Test
```

Comment: +1, nice answer, though using a CTE means that this can be used for SQL Server 2005+ (wich should be the case anyway, since no one should use SQL Server 2000 on this year)

Comment: @Lamak -- thanks and you are absolutely correct.  I'll edit the answer to show the "uglier" version :)

Comment: It has to be based on some sort of assumptions. Otherwise it will break [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1c3c1/1)

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace `@s` with your `column name` to apply this to a table. Assuming that number is between last comma and space before the last comma. [Sql-Fiddle-Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/9045)

```
declare @s varchar(100) = '123.123.123.123, event 34, brown fox'

select right(first, charindex(' ', reverse(first),1) ) final
from (             
  select left(@s,len(@s) - charindex(',',reverse(@s),1)) first
  --from tableName
) X
```

***OR*** if it is between first and second commas then try, [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/9071)

```
select substring(first, charindex(' ',first,1), 
                 charindex(',', first,1)-charindex(' ',first,1)) final
from (             
  select right(@s,len(@s) - charindex(',',@s,1)-1) first
) X
```

Comment: Nice answer assuming there aren't numbers or commas after event 34, in which case, this wouldn't work (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/9046)

Comment: Yeah, based on the assumptions. !